# "Are you having a good day?" Is it about me or about the weather?

Tags: meaning

When I'm asked over the phone in a long-distance call "Are you having a good day?" is this a question about me (my mood, my health), or about the weather?

Assuming I'm speaking with a Brit, that is...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's about you, whether you're talking to a Brit or an American:

> Are **you** having a good day?

The weather is only pertinent as far as it affects *you* (e.g. you might answer *I'm drenched with rain.  Blah.*)  However, you are the main point of the question, and not the weather.

Answer (score 2):

If I was going to inquire about the weather, I would probably ask:

> *How's the weather there?*

In that case, you could answer:

> *It's a nice day.*

If you were a salesman, and I was asking about your job, I might ask:

> *How did things go yesterday?*

And, if you had made a lot of sales, you might answer:

> *I had a good day.*

But in your example, the subject (*you*) puts the *good day* in context.  They are not asking about the weather, or your sales; they are inquiring about you.